# Socket.io joining a room registers the room but only joins an empty string room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io/node.js/express.  When I join a socket.io room using socket.join('room'), it registers the room, but the user only joins the '' room.

This command shows all the rooms, it returns both 'room' and '', even though I never created the '' room:

```
console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms); // ['room', '']
```

This command shows all the rooms the client has joined, and it returns an empty string '':

```
console.log(io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]); // ['']
```

This command should broadcast a message to every client in the room.  It fails when using the actual room (data.chatroom).  But when you replace data.chatroom with **null** or '', it will broadcast the message to the empty string room:

```
io.sockets.in(data.chatroom).emit('broadcast_message',  {message: data.message, handle: data.handle});
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is very strange behavior :(

Edit: here is the relevant server code

```
var express = require('express'), 
app = express(),
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
routes = require('./routes'), 
chatroom = require('./routes/chatroom'),
path = require('path');

io.configure(function () {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join_room', function(data) {
        socket.join(data.chatroom);
        socket.emit('joined_room', data.chatroom);
    });

    socket.on('send_message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.in(data.chatroom).emit('broadcast_message',  {message: data.message, handle: data.handle});
    });
});

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/room/:chatroom', chatroom.create_room);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, every client that connects to the socket (socket.io server) is allocated to an empty room that is represented by an empty object or array, I can't remember now.

Here's the code that I use for joining clients to a room:

```
socket.room = "room1";
socket.join(socket.room);
```

and this is how you send messages: `socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("update", "A person has connected to " + room.name + " room.");`

I think you're missing the `socket.room` bit. Have a look at this repository: https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat

and the corresponding article:

http://tamaspiros.co.uk/2013/07/15/advanced-chat-using-node-js-and-socket-io-episode-1/